# How to access private members in friend function in header class

Tags: c++, class, header-files

I have created header file for definition of Class

Name.h

```
class Name
{

private:

    char* Fname;

    char* Lname;

public:

    Name(char* ='\0', char* ='\0');
    
    void setFname(char *);
    void setLname(char* );
    char* getFname();
    char* getLname();
    Name(Name& A);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Name&);
    ~Name();
};
```

but while accessing private member in friend function it show that n.Fname is inaccessible..

Name.cpp

```
ostream& std::operator<<(std::ostream& out, Name& n) {
    
out << "Name: " << n.Fname;

}
```

Comment: Did you remember to include your header?

Comment: What is the exact compiler error? (Or is it a runtime error maybe? Because the default values for your constructor are also wrong.)

Comment: Sometimes it's helpful to compare lines out of context. For example, in a new file, paste the friend declaration `friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Name&);` then on the next line paste the beginning of the implementation `ostream& std::operator<<(std::ostream& out, Name& n)`. Next, adjust for expected differences -- you know that the keyword `friend` should not be in the implementation, so remove it from the first line. Now look carefully at what's left character-by-character and see if there are any differences. Does rectifying those differences resolve the error?

Answer (score 1):

The **problem** is that while implementing the overloaded `operator<<` you've used  `std::operator<<` instead of just `operator<<`. This can be corrected by removing the qualification `std::` as shown below.

Additionally, you're missing a `return` statement inside the definition of overloaded `operator<<`.

```
//------------v----------------------------------------->removed the std:: from here
std::ostream&  operator<<(std::ostream& out, Name& n) {
    
out << "Name: " << n.Fname;
return out; //added return statement
}
```

---

Also, note that typically the second parameter to the overloaded `operator<<` is a reference to const (`const Name&` in your case) so that the declaration would look like:

```
class Name {
//other members
   
//----------------------------------------------------vvvvv--------->const added here
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&,const Name&);

};
//-----------------------------------------vvvvv-------------->const added here
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,const Name& n) {
    
out << "Name: " << n.Fname;
return out;
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/KIo01eSa1)